# Where is the problem in my struct declaration?

Tags: c, struct

Here is my code about suming 2 complex numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct complex {
    float real;
    float imag;
} complex;
complex result(complex n1, complex n2);
int main() {
    complex n1, n2;
    printf("For 1st complex number \n");
    printf("Enter the real and imaginary parts: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &n1.real, &n1.imag);
    printf("\nFor 2nd complex number \n");
    printf("Enter the real and imaginary parts: ");
    scanf("%f %f", &n2.real, &n2.imag);
    printf("Sum = %.1f + %.1fi", result(n1,n2).real, result(n1,n2).imag);
    return 0;
}
complex result(complex n1, complex n2) {
    (complex){.real = n1.real + n2.real};
    (complex){.imag = n1.imag + n2.imag};
}
```

And here is the output:

```
For 1st complex number 
Enter the real and imaginary parts: 1
1
For 2nd complex number Enter the real and imaginary parts: 1
1
Sum = 0.0 + 2.0i
```

I don't why only the .imag part of the result is passed from n1 and n2.

Comment: Did you try running your code through a debugger?

Comment: What is that function `result` supposed to do? You have two independent compound literals that have no effect and you do not return anything from that function as your compiler should tell you.

Comment: [Enable and heed your compiler's warnings!!!](https://godbolt.org/z/Pjjvce67W)

Answer (score 2):

This whole function does not do anything that is visible outside that function:

```c
complex result(complex n1, complex n2) {
    (complex){.real = n1.real + n2.real};
    (complex){.imag = n1.imag + n2.imag};
}
```

First of all, you don't return any value. Your compiler should show a warning about this.
Then you have 2 compound literals that you do not use. You don't assign it to anything or return it.
The compiler might also warn about this.

Your code does basically not much more than just `{0+1; 1+2;}` which is completely removed by the compiler.

What you probably want to do is this:

```c
complex result(complex n1, complex n2) {
  complex res = {.real = n1.real + n2.real,
                 .imag = n1.imag + n2.imag };
  return res;
}
```

or

```c
complex result(complex n1, complex n2) {
  return (complex){.real = n1.real + n2.real,
                   .imag = n1.imag + n2.imag };
}
```

Comment: oh thank you so much!

Comment: @NewbieBoy if that helped, you could accept the answer.